# Busemann function inequality

Tags: differential-geometry

In the book Peter Petersen about Differential Geom appear the next inequality

$b_t^{+}(x) \geq b^+(x) -  b^+(p)$

at the end of the page

[image]

im really confused because i dont know why. I have tried to prove but I only use the triangle inequality... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For this one, recall $\tilde \gamma^+$ is the limit of $\gamma_j$, where $\gamma_j$ is the geodesic from $p$ to $\gamma(t_j)$, where $t_j\to \infty$ is some sequence, and recall $\gamma$ is the line. We can compute 
$$
b^+(x)-b^+(p)=\lim_{j\to \infty} [d(x, \gamma(t_j))-t_j]-[d(p, \gamma(t_j))-t_j]
=\lim_{j\to \infty} d(x, \gamma(t_j))-d(p, \gamma(t_j)).
$$
Now $d(p, \gamma(t_j))=L$ is realized by the geodesic $\gamma_j$, so we can write 
$$
d(p, \gamma(t_j))=d(p, \gamma_j(t))+d(\gamma_j(t), \gamma_j(L)).
$$
Also note $\gamma_j(L)=\gamma(t_j)$, and $\gamma_j$ converges to $\tilde \gamma^+$. So
$$
\begin{aligned}
b^+(x)-b^+(p)=&\lim_{j\to \infty} d(x, \gamma(t_j))- d(p, \gamma_j(t))-d(\gamma_j(t), \gamma_j(L))\\
=&\lim_{j\to \infty} d(x, \gamma(t_j))- d(p, \tilde\gamma^+(t))-d(\tilde\gamma^+(t), \gamma(t_j))\\
\leq & d(x, \tilde\gamma^+(t))-d(p, \tilde\gamma^+(t))=d(x, \tilde\gamma^+(t))-t=b_t^+(x).
\end{aligned}$$